# Store a 'numeric' value starting with non-fixed number of 0 digits

Tags: r, class, variables

I need to store a fixed-length variable that might have a number of leading zeroes digits (e.g. "00045", "00657", "56748").

What class is best suitable to save the variable in in order to maintain said zeroes in place?

Both 'numeric' and 'character' give me problems, especially when the database is saved (csv format), closed, and re-read into R. Specifically, I do not understand why saving the variable as character fails me.

---

Edit:

```
# original data
df1 <- data.frame(x = c("00045", "00657", "56748"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(df1)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  1 variable:
#   $ x: chr  "00045" "00657" "56748"
write.csv(df1, "temp.csv", row.names = FALSE)

# no let's read, the str is not the same anymore
df2 <- read.csv("temp.csv")
str(df2)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
#   $ x: int  45 657 56748
```

Comment: Show us some example code where characters don't work.  They should.

Comment: When re-reading the file it might automatically convert the variable to numeric, did you specify col classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read the cv you can specify the column classes:

```
read.csv(yourCsvPath,colClasses =classVector)
```

use the parameter colClasses to specify the columns must be read as character:

> A vector of classes to be assumed for the columns. Recycled as necessary, or if the character vector is named,
>   unspecified values are taken to be NA.
>
> Possible values are NA (the default, when type.convert is used), "NULL" (when the column is skipped), one of the atomic vector classes
>   (logical, integer, numeric, complex, character, raw), or "factor",
>   "Date" or "POSIXct". Otherwise there needs to be an as method (from
>   package methods) for conversion from "character" to the specified
>   formal class.
>       Note that colClasses is specified per column (not per variable) and so includes the column of row names (if any).

Let me know if this work, if not we need to see your code!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Specifying the class vector upon re-reading the file solved the problem.